# Installing Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Express

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012-express

I'm using VS2012 which comes with SQl Server Express 2012, I also installed Sql Server management Studio.

Now, I'm creating an ASP Net App that will be hosted in IIS, after adding an Entity data Model defined with a Sql Server database, I tried to run the app, at that moment it told me to better install Sql Server Express with IIS, and suggested a Microsoft Page with the latest version of Sql Server Express.

I have my VS up to date with all upgrades, do I really need to install it?

[image]

I also have Local DB installed.

If I had to install it, can I do so without uninstalling the previous versions?, it would be kind of a mess since there are several related programs installed

Rafael

Comment: Have got checked if SQL Server Express is running as a service?

Comment: Also what's your connection string?

Comment: It's suggesting to configure your app to use IIS Express and Sql Express. It's not asking you to install it, only that if you haven't yet, you should.